# Перенаправить вывод консольной программы в файл

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, консоль

Имеется программа(нейронная сеть), она выводит большое количество информации, важной для дебага посредством `printf()`.

В виндовой консоли ничего, естественно, не умещается. Хотелось бы как-то перенаправить весь вывод(от начала работы программы и до конца) в файл, чтобы после завершения работы программы спокойно его прочитать. Гуглил, нашел предложения типа `program.exe > output.txt`, оно у меня не работает(насколько я понял, это из-за того, что программа интерактивная и требует ввода некоторых данных пользователем).

Работаю в Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас все работает (должно работать), просто все приглашения пользователю, тоже выводимые `printf`, идут в файл. Скорее всего, вы принимаете за "не работает" отсутствие приглашений ввода.

Либо переписывайте, либо при отладке просто вводите значения без всяких приглашений - вы-то знаете, что и когда надо ввести :) Можете даже запихнуть весь необходимый ввод в файл и вызывать

```
prog.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Действительно. Как Вы и написали, я ошибся, на самом деле, все работает, просто приглашения пользователю не выводятся в консоль.

Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Просто переоткройте ([freopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen)) в нужный момент (после окончания диалога) `stdout` на другой файл.

Имя этого файла можете передавать в аргументе `main`.

Т.е. как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  puts("Go...");
  // здесь весь диалог

  if (av[1])
    if (!freopen(av[1], "w", stdout))
      return perror(av[1]), 1;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d\n", i);

  // если требуется продолжить вывод в консоль
  if (av[1])
    freopen("con", "w", stdout);
  puts("End");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться программой [wtee](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wintee/downloads) - аналог команды tee из *nix (копирует вывод из программы и в терминал, и в файл): `yourprogram | wtee output.txt`. Будут видны приглашения ввода в терминале, плюс вывод программы сохранится в файл.

Comment: О. Полезная штука. Спасибо, теперь буду пользоваться:)

Answer (score 0):

А почему самой программой не создавать файл к примеру с датой в названии и не складывать в него результат ее работы? Например с помощью `fputs()` там где используется `printf()`

Comment: Да, конечно, я думал об этом варианте. Но переписывать придется очень много. Если не предложат никаких более быстрых вариантов, то придется делать так..